# UTF-8 characters not displaying correctly in Android or IE8

Tags: android, html, internet-explorer, utf-8

I set up a html page to test some UTF-8 characters before constructing a javascript tree widget (simulating a OS tree like in Explorer).
I start my page as:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
...
```

and here the results running my test-page **in Firefox:**

[image: Symbols Firefox]
[image]
(success!)

**in Android 4.1.2:**

[image: Symbols Android 4.1.2]
[image: Light Tree Android 4.1.2]
(partial failure)

**in IE8 under winXP:**

[image: Symbols IE8]
[image: Light Tree Win IE8]
(total failure)

What else can I do to correct the display of these chars?
Thanks.

Comment: Mysteriously Android lines up symbol └ (#x2514;) with symbol ╴ (#x2574;) but not Firefox(!)

Comment: This is a font issue.  The HTML needs to specify a font that supports the Unicode characters being used. The browser's default font is not likely to support everything, so you might need to install/embed a font that does.